# How to Stop SharePoind Designer Workflow from Looping Between Two Lists

Tags: 2010

I have two lists with identical Designer 2010 workflows that auto start when either lists item is updated. Each time one lists is updated, it starts the other lists workflow, causing a loop.  I simply can’t figure out how to stop the looping.  I’m using a Parent ID and Child ID relationship between items.

I’m desperate.  Thanks.